# Git: pull requests causing conflicts

Tags: git, github

I have a master and dev branch for one microservice, and one repo for each microservice of my app. Originally versioning was basic/singular amongst each microservice but we later segregated this so that each branch had their own pom version and dependency range.

However for one repo, this seemed botched and now I keep getting pom conflicts.

> Master:
> version 2.0.4,
> dependency range [2.0.0,3.0.0)

> Dev:
> version 1.1.1,
> dependency range [1.0.0,2.0.0)

Even when the version/range of master and dev are like the above example, when I raise a pull request from dev to master I will get pom conflict such that highlights an old version e.g.

Remove version 2.0.1 changes to 1.1.1

If I temporarily change dev version to 2.0.1, merge the updated pull request (master remains 2.0.4), and update dev back to 1.1.1, the conflict will come back if I raise another pull request.

It successfully ignores all other differences in pom between master and branch (e.g. the range) except for just the version.

Comment: This is normal. Just resolve the conflict each time.

Comment: Note that POM files use XML, and Git is terrible at resolving XML changes, especially computer-generated XML.